# Vue.js handling back button on crud navigation

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have a search form that fills a table with the results of an API query. Each item on the table have an edit button. When the user click on that button, a view is showed, with the detail of the item. The problem is when I want to go back to the list, I lost the last search result. What is the best way to solve this problem?

I see two approaches: In first one, I save the results of the query through Vuex, but I dont know if Vuex is used to save large amount of data. On the second approach, I show/hide the components instead of change the route: when I want to edit an item, I hide the table and show the edit view. When I want to go back to the list, I hide the edit view and show the table. Is there another way to solve  this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By last search result, What you mean? Are there any filters on that table which you want to store?

Comment: @ParidhiJain, I dont want to lose the filters and the info which was on the table.

Comment: Use localstorage to save your filters.

Comment: I try to avoid calling the API again.